# How take value from async method in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, subscribe

I need to call/subscribe to the external service observable method and take value from it. I try it, it component constructer but always return undefined. I examine put console.log inside the method the value is there. need some expert helpt to take this object ->string value in angular.

```
     this.x:string; 
        constructor(
        private readonly socService: ocService) { }
    
        
      ngOnInit(): void {
       
    
        this.ocService.getActiveoc().subscribe(oc => { this.x= oc.id });
        
        //TODO For Testing
        if(this.x){
          console.log("ID" + this.x)
          this.store.dispatch(selectPatientAction({ x: this.x}));
        }
      }

   onScanX() {
    this.store.dispatch(scanX({x: this.x }));
    this.isocSelected = true;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you want to do with that value should be done in the `subscribe` method. Dispatch your action in that method too.

I'm assuming you are using NgRedux here.

```
    constructor(
       private readonly socService: ocService
       private store: NgRedux<AppState>
     ) { }
    
        
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.ocService.getActiveoc().subscribe(oc => { 
          this.x = oc.id;
          this.store.dispatch(selectPatientAction({ x: this.x}));
        });
      }

   onScanX() {
    this.store.dispatch(scanX({x: this.x }));
    this.isocSelected = true;
  }
```

Comment: I am a very beginner of angular can you please, show me example. I need assing that id also for using another method ?

Comment: Can you post the method that you need the id for and how you are using it?

Comment: Skeleton , it thanks full even, you can please show me how to call event inside the dispatcher. I try to search a lot of articles but still couldn't resolve it.

Comment: Thank you som much.. it is working now. i will do more testing

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo in this section?

```
this.ocService.getActiveoc().subscribe(soc => { this.x= oc.id });
```

I think it should be `soc.id` rather than `oc.id`?

Comment: Can i get the screenshot about the payload of oc?